# Ruby mailer with sidekiq into Rails 5.x app : ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, sidekiq, mailer

I'm trying to migrate from rails 4.x to rails 5.x

gemfile.lock:
- rails (5.0.2)
- sidekiq_mailer (0.0.8)
- sidekiq (5.0.0)
- actionmailer (= 5.0.2)

For mailing stuff, when I try the following :
`$>UserMailer.password_reset(account_to_reset).deliver_later`
(which previously worked like a charm)
I got this error :
 
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)`

with (the full and only) following backtrace :

from /Users/nathangouy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:582:in 'initialize'
    from /Users/nathangouy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sidekiq_mailer-0.0.8/lib/sidekiq_mailer/proxy.rb:11:in 'new'
    from /Users/nathangouy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sidekiq_mailer-0.0.8/lib/sidekiq_mailer/proxy.rb:11:in 'actual_message'
    from /Users/nathangouy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sidekiq_mailer-0.0.8/lib/sidekiq_mailer/proxy.rb:28:in 'method_missing'

I try a lot of things and wasn't able to find any similar issue on sidekiq or actionmailer

Comment: this is argument passing error, paste code of UserMailer also

Comment: The problem is that I have a byebug that is never triggered at the very beginning of my `password_reset` method (even after restart rails s/c + sidekiq etc ...) then I think the problem doesn't come from it (and then I didn't share it here). Am I right ?

Comment: use `pry` gem for debugging code..and add `binding.pry` in view to debug code rather than `byebug`

Comment: Well i just tried some things with pry but it doesn't help me much. When I try to look on the core code, the fact is that sidekiq-mailer try to init an Action mailer the old way: actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/base.rb#l580 :`def initialize(method_name=nil, *args)` when now its :  actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/base.rb#l582 : `def initialize` (no params)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, the thing is that sidekiq_mailer isn't maintained by the sidekiq author (I missed this crucial info), and then it's not usable for now with sidekiq/rails 5.x